# normalizer with ngrx/store and OnPush change detection

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

I am trying to set up a project with ngrx/store and normalizer to flatten the data. I am finding that if I denormalize the data from the selector, then I can't(makes no difference) use OnPush change detection on the components. Due to the fact that denormalize returns new instances.

Is there a way around this? At which level is best to handle denormalize?